# MVC Core редирект авторизаци на https, а не на http

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Приложение запущено за прокси apache2 на ubuntu. При переадресации на страницу авторизации редирект происходит не на httpS а на http.

```
 .AddCookie(options =>
           {
               options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login");
               options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Account/Login");

           });
```

Сертификат установлен на apache. Как правильно сделать редирект на httpS?

Comment: core >= 2.1 [UseHttpsRedirection](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/18.6.php), [офдока](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: это как понял редирект если сам сертификат стоит в преложении, а тут за веб прокси

Comment: Сделал редирект на веб прокси.